# Const access from outside a class contained in string

Tags: php, constants

With this code:

```
<?php

class Constants{
   const ONE = 1;
   const TWO = 2;
   const THREE = 3;
}

$input = "ONE";

echo Constants::$input;

?>
```

I want to access to the constants inside the class having the name in a variable.

I'ts that posible.

Comment: `Contants` < look at that again. *Typo*

Comment: Is the typo in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`constant`](https://www.php.net/constant) function will return value of a constant by its name:

```
class Contants{
   const ONE = 1;
   const TWO = 2;
   const THREE = 3;
}

$input = "ONE";

echo constant(Contants::class . '::' . $input);
```